# How to keep a distribution updated from upstream project?

Tags: git, open-source, git-fork

I have a private distro of an Open Source project (with some changes specific to my environment).

I'd like to keep these changes early integrated with the upstream project.
For that reason, I'd like to create a fork where my changes are merged to the master branch, as well as to any existing and new version/release branch.

The part I'm not sure about is how to create new release branches in a clean way.